# React Router Links are double rendering components

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, render

React Router links seem to be double rendering components. Can anyone duplicate my results below:

When the page first loads you will get "RENDERING HOME" logged once. But then using the links will always log the "RENDERING" line twice.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


class home extends React.Component {
    render(){
        console.log('RENDERING HOME');
        return(
            <Link to='destination'>Link to Destination</Link>
        )
    }
}

class destination extends React.Component {
    render(){
        console.log('RENDERING DESTINATION');
        return(
            <Link to='/'>Link to Home</Link>
        )
    }
}

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return(
          <Router history={hashHistory}>
              <Route path='/' component={home}/>
              <Route path='destination' component={destination}/>
          </Router>
      );
  },
});


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

EDIT: This appears to be a bug, others have noted it on the react-router github. Its only a bug with hashHistory. Switching to browserHistory resolves the issue.

Comment: You're saying when changing the path that both `console.log` functions run?

Comment: No, if you click on the destination link "RENDERING DESTINATION" will log twice. Meaning the destination component renders twice. Note changing the path doesn't have this result. If I just navigate to destination manually it will only render once. It is specifically using the Link component that double renders.

Comment: I think it's because you don't have the destination route nested inside the root route. Try this: Place an `IndexRoute` and the destination route under the root route. Then the `IndexRoute` `component` should be `home`. The parent root route should be a container for your entire app.

Comment: No, it still double renders, only now rendering both the container and the child component twice. So one click on the Link and you will get the following logged:

    RENDERING CONTAINER
    RENDERING DESTINATION
    RENDERING CONTAINER
    RENDERING DESTINATION

And if you click on the Home link it will render container and home twice.

I think this is just a bug that React-Router is aware of. Should I close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with hashHistory, please refer to this link:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4266

To solve it for now, consider using browserHistory and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change router. add / in destination

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
              <Route path='/' component={home}/>
              <Route path='/destination**' component={destination}/>
  </Router>
```

**add destination route inside root route**

> ```
> <Router history={hashHistory}>
>        <Route path='/' component={home}>
>           <Route path='destination**' component={destination}/>
>         </Route> </Router>
> ```

Comment: Neither of these suggestions work. Adding the / doesn't change anything, you don't need a / for the route to work. And it still double renders.

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion just breaks the thing. The destination component no longer renders since the "Home" component doesn't have a reference to {props.children}. Since the /destination path is a child of the home path, the home component will always render and unless it is referencing its child routes you will never see them.